# Displaying items of the same name in Android SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, cursor

I'm using this below to add map markers to a Google Map. I have a table column FIELD_NAME. There are several locations each tied to a same FIELD_NAME. So for example there may be 5 entries of FIELD_NAME Woods with each entry having its own latitude/long value. I'm trying to figure out how to query the table to provide the FIELD_NAME but I only want it to show one of each name, not every time it is used. Once I get the name I will use it to display all the lat long points of that selected FIELD_NAME. How do you do this and does anyone have any links to tutorials on queries of this type?

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0,
    Cursor arg1) {
int locationCount = 0;
double lat=0;
double lng=0;


// Number of locations available in the SQLite database table
locationCount = arg1.getCount();

// Move the current record pointer to the first row of the table
arg1.moveToFirst();

for(int i=0;i<locationCount;i++){

    // Get the latitude


    name = arg1.getString(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_NAME));

    lacomments = arg1.getString(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_COMMENTS));

    lat = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT));

    // Get the longitude
    lng = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG));






    // Creating an instance of LatLng to plot the location in Google Maps
     locationEngine = new LatLng(lat, lng);


     MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();                 

        markerOptions.position(locationEngine);

        // Adding marker on the Google Map
        getMap().addMarker(markerOptions);  




    arg1.moveToNext();


}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried to make the search on the [WHERE](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/where.php) clause in your SQL query ? It will directly return the row that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to populate distinct FIELD_NAME in some spinner and then on selection of it display all the location for that, better do it with 2 queries

bind the spinner with result of 
"select distinct FIELD_NAME from tablename"

and then once user provides his selection, use the below query

select * from tablename where FIELD_NAME ='whatever_user_selected'

Note: tablename - replace with your table's name

> Let me know if there is not UI for user selection and you want random
>   entries for a specific field